# Excel - VBA - Search for updated OR new rows and merge

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a hell of a time with this one.  I've managed to automate the file handling portions of this new job for creating a new daily report for my group, but the most annoying step is updating the master files with the new dumps from the FTP.

This is an amalgam of code i've scrounged/copied and some things I wrote myself, so it's a hot mess I know.

Here's the run down.

1. I receive 4 files daily via FTP, 1 for 4 different states
2. These files are auto-archived and then the newest version of each is
   renamed to the two letter state name (i.e. IL.csv) and moved to a
   fresh data folder.
3. I have an intermediate file in a shared network drive that needs to
   allow for manual data entry from each state daily on actual
   performance that I need to auto-merge any updated values or new rows
   of data into from the files in step 2
4. I already have a query and cleanup run that merges the 4
   intermediate files from step 4 into the master workbook that I can
   auto-generate my reports from.

The part that's killing me is figuring out how to read from the daily files, evaluate against the intermediate files and update certain columns if changed and add any new rows (the previous day's activity).

I *definitely know* that my select copy isn't accurate or working below, but I can't even get the upper portion to open and select from the files to work correctly, I keep getting "object doesn't support this property or method" on OldRange and NewRange.

```
Sub UpdateDataWithNew()

Dim ILmain As Workbook
Dim ILnew As Workbook
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim maintable As Worksheet
Dim OldRange As Integer
Dim NewRange As Integer
Dim ListOld As Range
Dim ListNew As Range
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range


Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\adeno\Desktop\Test Load 
Files\Illinois.xlsm"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\adeno\Desktop\Today's FTP\IL.csv"
Set ILmain = Workbooks("Illinois.xlsm")
Set ILnew = Workbooks("IL.csv")
OldRange = ILmain.Range("A2", 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
NewRange = ILnew.Range("A2", 
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Set ListOld = Range("B2:B" & OldRange)
Set ListNew = Range("B2:B" & NewRange)

Set data = ILnew.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set maintable = ILmain.Sheets("Sheet1")


For Each x In ListOld
    Workbook.ILnew.Activate
    If Application.CountIf(ListB, x) = 0 Then
    Row.Copy
    Workbook.ILmain.Activate
    Row.End(x1Up).Select
    Cells.PasteSpecial
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: -- I am having a hard time following step 3., step 4., and the part thats killing me;;; and then trying to figure out if the code sample applies to 3 or 4 or killing... Can you spend some time to edit the above and clarify?  This seems like a transaction file updating a master file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Long` instead of `Integer`. It is easy to max out any integer values in modern Excel (the number of possible rows is greater than what an integer can hold).

Your problem could how you set the last row, with parameters that Excel/VBA don't recognise

```
'Original bad code
    OldRange = ILmain.Range("A2", Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
```

You simply want to get the last row, because you set the real range on the following lines and you take into account the header row then.

```
OldRange = ILmain.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
```

I have used `xlUp` because going `xlDown` may stop at the first blank cell rather than after the last populated cell (I think, have not tested this myself).